# Blank boxes in high chart when data is null

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I am using area range & line high chart graphs to do some graphical representation.I have a requirement to show sided boxes [bars] when there is no data[null] for some days.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: averages,
        zIndex: 1,
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'white',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Range',
        data: ranges,
        type: 'arearange',
        lineWidth: 0,
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        zIndex: 0,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
```

Fiddle -    https://jsfiddle.net/anishkpn/4epsn04x/

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Could you add an image of the required chart?

Comment: Just add a column series where only the otherwise null points are represented. Style accordingly, and set the y values at whatever is appropriate for you purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a new series that represents the `null` values:

```
boxes = [
  [1247529600000, 1],
  [1247616000000, 1],
  [1247702400000, 1],
  [1247788800000, 1],
  [1247875200000, 1],
  [1247961600000, 1]
];
```

Plot as a column series:

```
{
  name: 'Boxes',
  type: 'column',
  data: boxes,
  color: 'transparent',
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
  groupPadding: 0,
  pointPadding: 0.2
}
```

Fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3gxk79b3/

Or, if you want the boxes at some point other than the base line, use a `columnrange` series instead, and float them wherever you want:

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3gxk79b3/1/

Output:

[image]

Alternatively, use the `Renderer()` function, and draw whatever you want:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer

Comment: I want it as one box from july 14 to 19